# Changing Gridview groups row background color

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an asp.net application. I have a gridview where I am grouping the results based on order number:

I am using this code:

```
void GroupGridView(GridViewRowCollection gvrc, int startIndex, int total)
    {
        if (total == 0) return;
        int i, count = 1;
        ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
        lst.Add(gvrc[0]);
        var ctrl = gvrc[0].Cells[startIndex];

        for (i = 1; i < gvrc.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell nextCell = gvrc[i].Cells[startIndex];
            Label lblNextOrderID = nextCell.FindControl("lblOrderID") as Label;
            Label lblOrderID = ctrl.FindControl("lblOrderID") as Label;
            if (lblOrderID.Text == lblNextOrderID.Text)
            {
                count++;
                nextCell.Visible = false;
                lst.Add(gvrc[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (count > 1)
                {
                    ctrl.RowSpan = count;
                    ctrl.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
                    GroupGridView(new GridViewRowCollection(lst), startIndex + 1, total - 1);
                }

                count = 1;
                lst.Clear();
                ctrl = gvrc[i].Cells[startIndex];
                lst.Add(gvrc[i]);
            }
        }
        if (count > 1)
        {
            ctrl.RowSpan = count;
            GroupGridView(new GridViewRowCollection(lst), startIndex + 1, total - 1);
        }
        count = 1;
        lst.Clear();
    }
```

and calling it like this:

```
  gvOrderHistory.DataSource = gridDataSource;
                gvOrderHistory.DataBind();
                GroupGridView(gvOrderHistory.Rows, 0, 1);
```

I am following this [link](http://techbrij.com/grouping-gridview-rows-asp-net). Now I want that Color of alternate groups should be different ( not alternate rows). One group should be green. then next group white and then third group again green and then white and so on. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column to the gridview and give different numbers for different groups and then in RowDataBound event handler of the grid, you can change the color of row based on the column number.

You can set the color of row like:
   e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;

Answer (score 0):

If Im reading your code right, couldn't you just reference your ctrl variable and use the attributes property?  For example:

```
ctrl.Attributes.Add("class", "classname");
```

I wasn't sure what variable you're trying to apply this to, but this would work for your nextCell TableCell object as well..

HTH

Comment: I need alternate rows to be colored not all

Answer (score 0):

first add a css class to your aspx form

```
<style>
    .green { background-color: #00ff21; }
</style>
```

then add the extra codes as shown below

```
        ....
   ==>  int x = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < gvrc.Count; i++)
        {

   ==>      if(x % 2 == 0) gvrc[i].CssClass = "green";
   ==>      x++;

            TableCell nextCell = gvrc[i].Cells[startIndex];
            if (ctrl.Text == nextCell.Text)
            {

             ....
```